# drawable xml shape color change dyanamically

Tags: android, seekbar, xml-drawable, android-selector

I am using the `SeekBar`, I need to use the different color `SeekBar`'s progress in the list.

So I need to change the drawable shape color programmatically

this is the drawale xml.
seekbar_points.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/points_bg" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/points_progress" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

points_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

points_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="@color/color7" />
</shape>
```

[image]

I have to change this green color area dynamically. for this I have set the color points_progress.xml in this xml

Please suggest the idea 
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(сontext, R.color.color_new), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

**Update:**
If you want to change color for progressed area only:

```
LayerDrawable progressDrawable = (LayerDrawable) seekBar.getProgressDrawable();
Drawable filledDrawable = progressDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);
filledDrawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(сontext, R.color.color_new), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: I got the class cast exception here

Comment: seekbar.getProgressDrawable() returns `X extends Drawable`. Can you post returned specific class for it?

Comment: @CarinaMj I've changed to simple code for your situation

Comment: If I used this code then changing the whole background. But, I need to change the background for progressed area color only. Background should use as the same. but the selected area should change dynamically... please check the updated question with image

Comment: @CarinaMj I've added example for changing background for progressed area only.